# Serve different page based on variable with Nginx

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, jamstack, nuxt-i18n

I have a `nuxt generate`d JAMStack website with i18n. Generated pages are located in `en` and `ru` folders.  I'm calculating user's locale and serving content from the corresponding folder:

```
map $http_accept_language $fallback_lang {
    ~en en;
    ~ru ru
    default en;
}

map $cookie_i18n_redirected $lang {
    en en;
    ru ru;
    default $fallback_lang;
}

server {
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        try_files /$lang/$uri /$lang/$uri/index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Russian frontpage lies in `/ru/index.html`, but English version has no such page and I would like to serve `/en/archive/index.html` in response for `GET /` if `$lang` is `'en'`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to leverage the built in `extendRoutes` in the `nuxt.config.js`.

In your *nuxt.config.js* file:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
  ...

  router: {
    ...
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        path: '/',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/en/archive/index.vue')
      });
    }
    ...
  },
```

That would allow you at the application level to route to a specfic nuxt page depending on the incoming route.

Comment: This only might work if wrapped inside a condition like `if (process.env.GENERATE_LOCALE === 'en') routes.push ...` to limit execution to generation of certain locale.

I'm trying to keep my Nuxt app functional in spa/universal mode as well. So what I have currently seems to work better: `async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next): {
 await next((vm) => if (vm.$i18n.locale === 'en') vm.$router.replace('/archive')
}`. Nginx approach, on the other hand, could possibly work in all modes as I am reverse proxying everything through it. That's why I am looking for such a solution.